# Change of variables to evaluate double integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, jacobian

Use the change of variables $x=\sqrt{u+v}$, $y=v$ to evaluate: 
$\iint x\,dx\,dy$

over the region R in the first quadrant of the $xy$-plane bounded by $y=0$, $y=16$, $y=x^2$, and $y=x^2−9.$

I'm pretty lost. I tried to find the Jacobian, and I got $(1/2\sqrt{u+v})-(1/2\sqrt{v+u})$. 
I also tried to find the bounds for $x$ and $y$. However, I have no idea if I'm even on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

$x = \sqrt {u+v}\\y = v$

jacobian:

$dy\ dx = $$\det \pmatrix {\frac {\partial x}{\partial u}&\frac {\partial x}{\partial v}\\\frac {\partial y}{\partial u}&\frac {\partial y}{\partial v}}\ du\ dv\\
 \det \pmatrix{\frac {1}{2\sqrt {u+v}}&\frac {1}{2\sqrt {u+v}}\\ 0&1} = \frac {1}{2\sqrt {u+v}} \ du\ dv$

Limits:

$y = x^2\\
v = u+v\\
u = 0$

$y = x^2-9\\
u = 9$

The limits for v:

$y = 0\\
v = 0$

$y = 16\\
v = 16$

$\int_0^{16}\int_0^{9} \frac 12 \ du\ dv$